# How to access picture on windows shared server from Android

Tags: android, kotlin, windows-share

Im building scanning software for a handheld computer with scanning capabilities. Its running Android 8.1. The device and server are on the same network and a ping confirmed that.

What I am trying to accoplish is to scan an ID. Then the picture should show in the allowcated `Image View`.

I am struggling to path to the file. On my computer I have the path as the following:

> //vs-12.vs.localnet/sigma/bmp/sheets/S1486423.jpg.

What I have in my code:

> \\vs-12.vs.localnet\sigma\BMP\Sheets\$plate.jpg.

Please let me know if its possible and where I need to make adjustments.